# mongomapper and rails view for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, view

i have a rails controller grabbing some data from mongodb. the field i'm interested in is actually an array and i would like to expose this in an erb view.

my current hack is to just set the javascript variable in the view directly (where item.array = [ "one", "two" ]):

```
var array = <%= item.array %>;
```

however, i see that the code is coming out escaped such that the html is coming out like

```
var array = [&quot;one&quot;, &quot;two&quot;];
```

is there a helper function i can use so that i can set the array directly in the javascript?

(long term is to move this into a json call, but i just want to get something working for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use as per below:

```
var array = <%= item.to_s.html_safe %>;
```

Comment: i get back: undefined method `html_safe' for ["one", "two"]:Array

Comment: Please, try this  : var array = <%= item.to_a.html_safe %>

Comment: same :( however, you got me thinking and i did: var array = <%= item.to_s.html_safe %> instead and that worked! thanks

Comment: Please, can u accept answer,I was update answer as per solution, so other's developer find right solution.